# Error - Deleting files in java returning false

Tags: java, string, file

I am trying to delete a file from a directory using Java with the following code:

```
static String deleta ="C:\\res\\in\\CANteste2.xml";
.
.
.
Boolean file = new File (deleta) .delete();
System.out.println ("file:" + file);
```

Permissions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwKGw.jpg

But it returns always `false` with no errors

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to delete the file with the user you are running Java with? That could be a potential cause.

Comment: Or even simpler - are you sure the file actually exists (and you don't have any typo in the path/name)?

Comment: @Mureinik Yeah, its correct

Answer (score 0):

You should use try and catch code for deleting the files 
if using java 7 then use Files API

or try to check the `File exists()` method before deleting file

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Comment: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo. (the archive in used by another process)

Answer (score 0):

I see some compilation errors in the code snippet.

1. `System.out.println (file:" + file);`

This statement will not compile. Probably you meant:

```
    System.out.println ("file: "+file);
```

2. The three lines will not be present in a single method. Reason is that you have declared the `deleta` variable as `static`. This means that you have to make it Class level. Thus, if you make `deleta` and `file`  as Class level variables, you cannot have the `System.out.println ("file: "+file);` in the Class Level. The Syso statement should be in a method.

Finally your code should look like:

```
public class Test {
static String deleta = "C:\\res\\in\\CANteste2.xml";
Boolean file = new File(deleta).delete();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.print();
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("file: " + file);
}
}
```

This code will return TRUE if the file was PRESENT and is now DELETED. It will return FALSE if the file is not found in the directory.

So the first instance you will run the code, you will get the output as TRUE (if the file is present). From the second instance onwards, you will get the output as FALSE, as it has already been deleted!

Comment: 2. I added in the post the images of directory

Comment: 2. Its static  because in my code, "delete" its outside of the method